# Why custom resource records in Google DNS panel is not working?

Tags: google, domains, dns

I bought a domain from [domains.google](https://domains.google/).

Then I went into my panel, connected it to Google Sites, and then I went on to create custom DNS resource records for my subdomains.

Google Sites works perfectly. But my subdomains are not resolving.

---

[image]

---

For example, I have added these records. But when I use nslookup to query them, or when I enter them in browser, I get non-existent error. I have waited for more than 72 hours now.

[image]

---

What should I do?

Comment: How did you connect it to Google sites?  Did you change the `NS` records or did you set `A`, `ALIAS`, and `CNAME` records?

Comment: Have you tried any DNS diagnostic tools?   I usually use `dig` on the command line.  First I query the `NS` records: `dig NS example.com` then I query the given name server for the desired subdomain `dig @ns1.dnshost.example accounts.example.com`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, as I said in the question, I have connected it to Google Sites. I have not changed the NS records. I just added a couple of custom resource records. Also when I `nslookup -type=ns accounts.x.y` I get Non-existent domain. However, when I `nslookup -type=ns x.y` I get results.